# Access the cpython string format specification mini language parser

Tags: python, string-formatting, cpython

EDIT:

I have created a module to provide this functionality. It might not be that great but it can be obtained [here](https://gist.github.com/Ricyteach/6663a4b76d63cb806f3002fb3a89a1e3).

### Original Question

I need to be able to parse format strings (as specified by the [string format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)). A project I'm working on makes heavy use of the [`parse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) module for "unformatting" of strings. The module allows for creating customized format codes/formulas. My intent is to automatically parse certain kinds of format strings in a manner somewhat consistent with the existing string format specification mini language.

To clarify: by "format strings", I mean those strings that are used when using the `format` function and `format` method of `str` objects, e.g.:

```
'{x!s: >5s}'.format('foo') # the format string is ' >5s'
```

I have taken a look at the [cpython string module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/string.py) and line # 166 looks to me like it is saying that parsing of the format string is handled in the `_string` module.

```
# The overall parser is implemented in _string.formatter_parser.
```

This occurs at this line (# 278):

```
return _string.formatter_parser(format_string)
```

I am pretty unfamiliar with the cPython code base and am not much of a C programmer, and I could not find the `_string` module. I am wondering if it is implemented at the C language level...?

Main question: is the format specification parsing implementation exposed somewhere for use? How can I get to it so I don't have to write my own? I am looking to get output something like this:

```
>>> parse_spec(' >5.2f')
{'fill': ' ', 'align': '>', 'sign': None, '#': None, '0': None, 'width': 5, ',': None, 'precision': 2, 'type': 'f'}
```

### EDIT

Note that the comments say that, despite its name, `_string.formatter_parser` does not do what I am after.

```
# returns an iterable that contains tuples of the form:
# (literal_text, field_name, format_spec, conversion)
# literal_text can be zero length
# field_name can be None, in which case there's no
#  object to format and output
# if field_name is not None, it is looked up, formatted
#  with format_spec and conversion and then used
def parse(self, format_string):
    return _string.formatter_parser(format_string)
```

Comment: I'd just write the regex and be done with it. I'm pretty sure what you're looking for isn't exposed in any way.

Comment: I don't know s--- about regex. Should probably finally get around to watching [this PyCon talk.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abrcJ9MpF60)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format specification is specific to each object; it is parsed by the [`__format__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) of an object. For example, for string objects, that method is implemented in C as the [`unicode__format__` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L13744-L13765).

A lot of the format is shared between object types, and so is the code to handle it. The [`formatter_unicode.c` file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Python/formatter_unicode.c) handles most format-string parsing. Within this file, the [`parse_internal_render_format_spec()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Python/formatter_unicode.c#L156-L324) does most of the parsing.

Unfortunately, this function is not exposed to Python code. Moreover, it is declared as `static`, so you can't access it externally (for instance, via a [`ctypes` wrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)), either. Your only options are to either re-implement it, or to re-compile your Python source code with the `static` keyword removed from the function, and then access it via the shared library.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Time to learn something new I guess.

Comment: It's `static`, so I don't think ctypes can even get at it.

Comment: @user2357112 But what if I want it bad enough?

Comment: @user2357112: ah, indeed, `pythonapi.parse_internal_render_format_spec` raises `AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, parse_internal_render_format_spec): symbol not found`. Indeed, static functions are not exported.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who comes upon this question needing to do this, here is a regex I came up with to match what I'm calling a format string (this [PyCon 2017 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abrcJ9MpF60) was invaluable in my being able to come up with this so quickly!):

```
r=r'([\s\S]?[<>=\^])?[\+\- ]?[#]?[0]?\d*[,]?(\.\d*)?[sbcdoxXneEfFgGn%]?'
import re
c=re.compile(r)
```

That should match any valid string as specified by the string format specification mini language. I have done some limited testing and it seems to work.

Now I need to take this and figure out how to parse out all the pieces of data I need. Will update when I figure out how to do that.

EDIT:

I've almost got it. The trick is to add group markers to the regex (i.e., parentheses) so you can access them later. This seems to work well:

```
r=r'([\s\S]?[<>=\^])?([\+\- ])?([#])?([0])?(\d)*([,])?(\.\d*)?([sbcdoxXneEfFgGn%])?'

from collections import namedtuple as nt
FormatSpec = nt('FormatSpec', 'fill_align sign alt zero_padding width comma precision type')

import re
spec = FormatSpec(*re.search(r,'x>5.2f').group(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

This results in:

```
FormatSpec(fill_align='x>', sign=None, alt=None, zero_padding=None, width='5', comma=None, precision='.2', type='f')
```

I'd like to figure out how to access the fill and align characters separately, and to get rid of the decimal marker in the `precision` portion, but this is a good start.

EDIT:

Nested groups are created and accessed by just adding the additional parentheses; they are assigned a group number in the order they are encountered:

```
r=r'(([\s\S])?([<>=\^]))?([\+\- ])?([#])?([0])?(\d)*([,])?((\.)(\d)*)?([sbcdoxXneEfFgGn%])?'

from collections import namedtuple as nt
FormatSpec = nt('FormatSpec', 'fill align sign alt zero_padding width comma precision type')

import re
spec = FormatSpec(*re.search(r,'x>5.2f').group(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12)) # skip groups not interested in
```

Results in this, which is exactly what I'm after:

```
FormatSpec(fill='x', align='>', sign=None, alt=None, zero_padding=None, width='5', comma=None, precision='2', type='f')
```

EDIT:

It seems to actually be better to *include* the decimal character in the `FormatSpec` tuple (separately) because the format specification can then be reconstructed directly:

```
r=r'(([\s\S])?([<>=\^]))?([\+\- ])?([#])?([0])?(\d)*([,])?((\.)(\d)*)?([sbcdoxXneEfFgGn%])?'

from collections import namedtuple as nt
FormatSpec = nt('FormatSpec', 'fill align sign alt zero_padding width comma decimal precision type')

import re
spec = FormatSpec(*re.fullmatch(r,'x>5.2f').group(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12)) # skip groups not interested in
```

Additionally, I have changed to the `r.fullmatch` method (rather than `search` or `match`) so that the pattern has to be matched exactly.

Now we can do this to reconstruct the provided format spec:

```
''.join(s for s in spec if s is not None)
# 'x>5.2f'
```